# Pushforward sheaf of a sheaf on a singleton?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm trying to understand the following proof:

> Proposition. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space. Then the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules has enough injectives.

> Proof. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf. For every $x \in X$, embed the stalk into an injective $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-modules, $\mathcal{F}_x \to I_x$. Let $j$ denote the inclusion of $\{x\}$ into $X$ and let $\mathcal{I} = \prod_{x \in X}j_*(I_x).$ (...)

I cut out the rest because I cannot decipher what it means by $j_*(I_x)$. I know that $j_*$ means the pushforward induced by $j$, but for that to make sense, doesn't $I_x$ have to be a sheaf? In this state, $I_x$ is just an $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module and I have no idea how to 'canonically' make sense of this as a sheaf on the singleton set $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must regard $I_x$ as a sheaf on the one point space. What have you tried? the topology of the singleton only has two opens, the empty set and the whole singleton. The sheaf condition fixes $I_x(\emptyset)$ (why?). Now, what should $I_x(\{x\})$ be?
Define this presheaf and prove it is a sheaf.

Once you do this, you can easily generalize it: a sheaf of sets on $\{x\}$ is just a set, a sheaf of rings is just a ring, a sheaf of groups is just a group, etc.

Comment: The locality axiom implies $I_x(\emptyset) = 0$, since for any section $s,t$ over $\{x\}$, $s=t$ vacuously holds. If I define $I_x(\{x\}) = I_x$, then I think this satisfies all sheaf axioms, am I missing anything?

Comment: @AnthonyLee Nope, if you verified it then that's all :)